# The difference between "sûreté" et "sécurité"?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Je n'arrive pas à comprendre la différence de sens entre **sécurité** et **sûreté**.

Comment: Sûreté est plus globale c'est ça ?

Comment: Apparémment j'avais tort, mais je pensais que la différence était un peu comme la différence entre *safety* (sûreté) et *security* (sécurité) en anglais.

Answer (score 3):

**Sécurité** : ce qui permet de se prémunir contre tout type de risques, de toutes natures, notamment technologiques, climatologiques, ...

**Sûreté**: sécurité axée sur la malveillance.

Exemple, *en matière aéronautique*, la **sécurité aérienne** concerne le bon fonctionnement des avions, les contrôles et mesures techniques (doublement des équipements, etc.), alors que la **sûreté aérienne** concerne la protection contre les actions malveillantes.

En anglais : *sécurité* => *safety*, *sûreté* => *security*, ce qui peut donner lieu à confusion.

voir notamment [wikipedia sur ce domaine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9curit%C3%A9_a%C3%A9rienne).

Comment: excellente explanation but can you elaborate more ... so that I can check it as ana answer.

Answer (score 3):

[*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s%C3%A9curit%C3%A9/71792/difficulte) dit "[d]ans le sens de « situation dans laquelle on ne craint aucun danger », les deux mots [sécurité et [sûreté]](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s%C3%BBret%C3%A9/75680) sont des quasi-synonymes et s'emploient presque indifféremment. Toutefois, l'usage a fixé certains emplois [...]" ; on parle de la *ceinture de sécurité*.

À la [*BDL*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=s%C3%A9curit%C3%A9&T3.x=0&T3.y=0), on a "[a]u sens d’« absence de risque, de menace », les deux noms sont synonymes. De plus, il n’y a pas de différence très marquée entre les locutions *en sécurité* et *en sûreté*. L’expression *en sécurité* veut parfois dire « dans un état d’esprit tranquille », mais elle signifie plus souvent « à l’abri du danger », comme *en sûreté*." On ajoute qu'en français moderne, *sécurité* est bien plus fréquent que *sûreté* (on parle de l'idée de confiance) et qu'il l'a remplacé dans bien des emplois. Puis on traite du caractère surtout figé de certaines locutions (*allumette de sûreté*, *épingle de sûreté* ; *agent de sécurité*, *ceinture de sécurité*, *équipement de sécurité*) où l'emploi de l'un ou l'autre dominerait, ainsi que d'autres nuances, et de [particularités](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1940) québécoises en contexte.

Une analyse attentive des entrées [*sécurité*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C3%A9curit%C3%A9) et [*sûreté*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C3%BBret%C3%A9) au *TLFi* permettrait sans doute (avec beaucoup d'efforts) de tirer de tels constats. Enfin on peut noter que la *sûreté* a un sens particulier (et important) en droit civil ([Fr](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do;jsessionid=A4A07ADD19F8B4FB3693C27B54041BFB.tpdila17v_1?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000006091495&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070721&dateTexte=20160216), [Qc](https://nimbus.mcgill.ca/pld-ddp/dictionary/show/8407?source=ED2FR)).

---

Selon le sens, ils *peuvent* être synonymes. Dans certaines locutions, la sélection est figée. *Sécurité* est devenu plus [fréquent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=s%C3%A9curit%C3%A9%2C%20s%C3%BBret%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cs%C3%A9curit%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cs%C3%BBret%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0) aujourd'hui et remplace *sûreté* dans certains emplois.

Comment: On peut ajouter les références du Robert : SÛRETÉ "1498; seurté XIIe "Gage, promesse assurance Assurance, caution garantie" avec homonyme actuel : assurance caution, garantie, gage, hypothèque nantissement, privilège  pour l'aspect pécuniaire -- vieilli syn. de sécurité. sinon en relation avec la police (notion de régulation, prévention) : Sûreté Nationale -- en littérature homon. assurance, certitude

Comment: Pour SÉCURITÉ (lié à sûr) les homonymes : assurance (de l'esprit, se croire à l'abri du danger) calme, confiance, tranquilité, avec les notion de défendre et protéger, les forces de Sécurité sont alors les CRS, avec notion d'ordre militaire -- P.S. vous pouvez intégrer ces commentaires dans votre réponse sans aucun problème :)

Comment: Si les termes sont proches, ils ne pas toujours interchangeables ; les homonymes fournis par le petit Robert (1993) éclairent les usages que vous avez cités.

Comment: Merci, je comprends, et il y a des nuances en effet. En fait j'ai relu et pensé intégrer un moment mais ce ne sont pas des citations verbatim etc. Je vous invite à rédiger une réponse avec deux citations, et à illustrer le champ de cette homonymie, l'esprit vs. les biens, le fait de policer vs. la défense. Autrement je vous invite p-ê à combiner vos 3 commentaires en 1 si possible, votre point étant aussi pertinent en commentaire. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

Voici l'[étymologie du mot sécurité selon le wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%C3%A9curit%C3%A9) :

> Emprunté au latin securitas (« exemption de soucis ; tranquillité
>   d'esprit »). Sécurité (du XIIe siècle mais rare avant le XVIIe siècle)
>   est considéré comme doublet savant de sûreté (en ancien français et
>   moyen français seürté), ce dernier terme étant toutefois attesté
>   depuis 1498 (Le Robert). Féraud note que « Sécurité et sûreté ne sont
>   pas la même chose ; le premier exprime un sentiment et l'autre un état
>   d'assurance ; on a souvent de la sécurité sans être en sûreté ».

La sûreté serait donc mesurable et « vraie » tandis que la sécurité serait une appréciation subjective et donc une opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Une bonne définition se trouve également dans l'article Wikipedia concernant la sureté:

> La sûreté est l'état de ce qui est sûr. De façon générale, il s'agit d'un état de protection contre le danger ou les menaces.
>
> C'est une notion qui se focalise essentiellement sur la protection contre les dangers qui viennent de l'extérieur [réf. nécessaire], à la différence de la sécurité qui, elle, est la condition de protection contre des défauts, des dommages, des erreurs, dangers, à caractère physique, financier, politique, émotionnel, psychologique, etc.

Source:
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BBret%C3%A9